# Logfiles indicate Googlebot trying to access suspicious URL's

Tags: googlebot, malicious

I am seeing suspicious URLs in my log files that look malicious leading to me being concerned about their intent.

Reverse IP checks out to be Googlebot so I cannot block these requests if which I am seeing about 100 requests each day and there are no security flags in Google Search Console.

I use Incapsula and they have also confirmed that it checks out as Googlebot, sample IP addresses are - 66.249.69.164, 66.249.65.226, 66.249.65.230.

The URL requests are structured like this:

`https://www.example.com/testforcookies?redirecturl=https%3a%2f%2foboteen.com%2fnude%2f13203-miley-cole-in-pool.php%0d%0a`

`https://www.example.com/testforcookies?redirecturl=https%3a%2f%2fmeasex.com%2fass%2f147152-ass-obsession-xhamster.php%0d%0a`

`https://www.example.com/testforcookies?redirecturl=https%3a%2f%2fpiosex.com%2fold%2f326911-sensual-blonde-babe-izolda.php%0d%0a`

`/testforcookies?redirecturl=` does form part of my site structure but the appended slug does not.

Thanks in advance for any advice anyone has on how to stop these requests.

Comment: How does your site respond to such requests? What does a _valid_ value for the `redirecturl` parameter look like (presumably it's an internal link)?

Comment: It leads to an error page - /errorpage.htm

Comment: What HTTP response does it send? 404? It looks like someone is trying to use your own internal redirect script in the hope they can forge backlinks from your site for Google to see.